# How to add javascript code to a LinkButton via server code c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I am creating a visual webpart with a linkbutton, the linkbutton is supposed to open a modal popup.

I already have the function defined, but I am not sure how to make the link button to fire a javascript function.

Pls see the CreateChildControls method

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function dialogfunction(pageUrl) {
                var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 900, height: 300 };
                SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
            }
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkButton" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>



  public partial class LinkButton : WebPart
    {
        // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the
        // Visual Web Part project item.
        private const string _ascxPath =@"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/VisualWebParts/LinkButton/LinkButton.ascx";

        private string _LinkText;
        private Uri _Link;


        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("LinkText"), WebDescription("Text for the link"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public string LinkText
        {
            get { return _LinkText; }
            set { _LinkText = value; }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("Link"), WebDescription("Link"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public Uri Link
        {
            get { return _Link; }
            set { _Link = value; }
        }

        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public LinkButton()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            LinkButton linkButton = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath) as LinkButton;
            if (linkButton != null)
            {
                linkButton.Title = LinkText;
                linkButton.TitleUrl = Link.ToString();
                Controls.Add(linkButton);
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use `LnkButton.OnClientClick = `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one line to your code:

```
linkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "dialogfunction('" + Link.ToString() + "');");
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can set the **onclick** attribute of your linkbutton to be javascript:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            LinkButton linkButton = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath) as LinkButton;
            if (linkButton != null)
            {
                linkButton.Title = LinkText;
                linkButton.TitleUrl = Link.ToString();

                /*************************************************************/
                /* you can replace "alert('test');" with any javascript
                i.e a function call */

                linkButton..Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('test'); ");
                /*************************************************************/

                Controls.Add(linkButton);
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `LinkOnClientClick` property, similar to your `LinkText` property, and use it to set the LinkButton's `OnClientClick` property.

```
public string LinkOnClientClick
{
    get; set;
}

protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
   LinkButton linkButton = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath) as LinkButton;
   if (linkButton != null)
   {
         linkButton.Title = LinkText;
         linkButton.TitleUrl = Link.ToString();
         linkButton.OnClientClick = LinkOnClientClick;
         Controls.Add(linkButton);
   }           
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to end your js onclientclick method by a return false; or else your LinkButton will do a PostBack

Comment: @Trajan yes, you're correct. I'd assumed a certain knowledge of JS and Web Forms technology, but it's definitely worth pointing that out.